# Hide content and then display the content within a tab table

Tags: php, drupal

I have a site where I have an availability calendar and I need to show it within a tab table, I have it working to show on both the content and then the tab table! How can I remove it from the content but still show it within the table? I have tried hiding it within the 'Manage Display' section of the content type but it removes it from both

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Description</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Availability</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Pricing Information</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home"><?php if(isset($node->field_cottage_description['und'][0]['value']))
            { 
                print $node->field_cottage_description['und'][0]['value'];
            }
            ?> </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            <?php
                print $content['field_availability']['#children'] ;

            ?></div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="messages"><?php if(isset($node->field_price_guide['und'][0]['value']))
            { 
                print $node->field_price_guide['und'][0]['value'];
            }
            ?></div>
</div>
```

I hope someone can help with my issue! If it's blatantly obvious then don't be afraid to  let me know.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to hide it but also keep it able to run is you just close it within the task manager...

if that dont work them you may have to turn it off and back on..

if that dont work them i think you may have to script it to be able to do what you are needing

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? Did you mean to answer this question?